# Invoke Spell Check automatically when closing document

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

Is it possible to make the spell check run when exiting a word document?  Although I know that the spell check is defaulted to highlight misspelled words/grammar errors, my boss has asked that I make the spell check run whenever someone exits a word document.

Answer (score 0):

Plug this into Visual Basic as a module--it will ask you if you want to run spell check in the event you really don't need to run a spell check:

Sub AutoClose()
    Dim iAnswer As Integer
    iAnswer = MsgBox("Run spell check?", _
      vbYesNo, "Spell check on closing")

```
If iAnswer <> 7 Then
    If Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling Then
        ActiveDocument.CheckGrammar
    Else
        ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling
    End If
End If
```

End Sub